# Redirect losing POST/SESSION DATA

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a problem with redirection, my whole code is working my only problem is losing a POST/SESSION data in the process. spent countless hours working with it and try alot of work arounds, but still it does not work and that is my only problem. here's my code

```
<?php 
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
// login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here 
// to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form. 

// This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
// If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
if(!empty($_POST)) { 
    // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
    // their username. 
    if(isset($_POST['validEmail'])) {
          $query = "SELECT *
                   FROM registered_email 
                   WHERE email = :validEmail"; 
    }

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( ':validEmail' => $_POST['validEmail'] ); 

    try { 
        // Execute the query against the database 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query");
    } 

    // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
    // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
    // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
    $login_ok = false; 

    // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
    // they entered is not registered. 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) { 

        if($_POST['validEmail'] === $row['email']) { 
            // If they do, then we flip this to true 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
    if($login_ok) { 
        $_SESSION['sesEmail'] = $row; 

        // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
        if (isset($_POST['validEmail'])) {
             echo "<script>location='http://www.url.com.ph/some.php'</script>";
        } 
    } else  { 
        // Tell the user they failed 
        print "Sorry to say that your Email is not Registered!."; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to have in all of header file set session_start()?

Comment: i used ob_start(); now , tried session_start(); too. still no luck. tried self posting it , the POST works. but when redirected its gone.

Comment: You can`t try with session_start() you must have it, show common file

Comment: You cannot use SESSION data unless EVERY script that uses it has a `start_session()` as pretty much the first line executed. I suggest you add it to your `common.php`

Comment: @rad11 its on the very top of my page

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay i'll try

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks guys, its my fault god im so dumb

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your code should look something like this, it should work fine as far as I see. I refactored your code and edited the redirect statement.

```
// I am assuming you have session_start(); included in common.php 
require("common.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST)) { 
    if(isset($_POST['validEmail'])) {
        $query = "SELECT *
               FROM registered_email 
               WHERE email = :validEmail"; 
        $query_params = array( ':validEmail' => $_POST['validEmail'] ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) { 
            die("Failed to run query");
        } 
        $login_ok = false; 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) { 
            if($_POST['validEmail'] === $row['email']) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 
        if($login_ok) { 
            $_SESSION['sesEmail'] = $row; 
            if (isset($_POST['validEmail'])) {
                // the page where you are redirecting should be linked with session as well
                echo "<script>window.location.href='http://www.url.com.ph/some.php'</script>";
            } 
        } else  { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            print "Sorry to say that your Email is not Registered!."; 
        } 
    }
    else  { 
        // Tell the user they failed 
        print "Sorry no POST parameters!."; 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. If not feel free to discuss.